# Javascript: Math.floor not working as expected

Tags: javascript

```
function TimeConvert(num) {
    for (i = 0; i < num; i+= 60) {
        if (num % 60 < 60) {
            var hours = Math.floor(i / 60);
            if (hours == 0) {
                var minutes = num % 60;
            } else {
                minutes = num % (60 * hours);
            }
        }
    }
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

When I call `TimeConvert(60)`, it returns `0:0` instead of `1:0`... why? Do I have to add a conditional to check whether `num % 60 == 0` in such cases?

Comment: Did you try tracing the code with a debugger?

Comment: `num % 60 < 60` is always satisfied if `num` is numeric and finite

Comment: Yes, it works when i call TimeConvert(126) for example, it returns 2:6. But when I call TimeConvert(120), it returns 1:0 and not 2:0.

Comment: trace with the value for which it misbehaves

Comment: Your condition is for less than your num;  try making it <=

Answer (score 5):

Why would you need to iterate ?

```
function TimeConvert(num) {
    var hours   = Math.floor( num / 60 );
    var minutes = num % 60;
    //minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes:minutes
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sZLQ4/)

Comment: IIUC, OP doesn't want to format the minutes as a two-digit number

Comment: @JanDvorak - just remove that line then!

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! You're right, I've got to stop thinking in terms of iteration all the time.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `i < num` it should be `i <= num` instead.
Your `for` is only executed once with `i=0`, because on the very next step `i` gets +60 and `i < num` becomes false.

And, anyway, the whole function should just be:

```
function TimeConvert(num) {
    var hours = Math.floor(num / 60);
    var minutes = num % 60;
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```